# Why does eclipse report an error when I use it under a hadoop account?

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, hadoop

I created two accounts, one is a common user, the other is just for hadoop, which is a superuser as root. I can load eclipse normally under my common user account, but I could not use it under hadoop account. I tried uninstalling eclipse and reinstalling it under the hadoop account but it still does not work.

Below is the error reported:

```
$ eclipse&
[1] 28486
hadoop@city-ubuntu:/home/city$ No protocol specified
No protocol specified

(eclipse:28487): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(eclipse:28487): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

** (eclipse:28487): WARNING **: The connection is closed

(eclipse:28487): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(eclipse:28487): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_display: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_display_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_n_monitors: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_monitor_geometry: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion `GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(eclipse:28487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_new: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

[1]+  Exit 139                eclipse
```

I installed eclipse with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you run `xhost +` as your normal user and then launch eclipse as `hadoop`?

Comment: @terdon, it reports : hadoop@city-ubuntu:/home/city$ xhost +city
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"

Comment: @terdon, now i run command xhost +localhost, then ssh -X hadoop@localhost eclipse, it can work now. but the hadoop plugin does not work! it can work under normal user.

Comment: Huh?Why are you `ssh`ing? Just run `xhost +` by itself, you can always reactivate it later. I am just thinking that your `hadoop` user might not have access to the X server which has been started by your normal user. So, if you disable X access control, it should work.

Comment: @terdon, now when i log in ubuntu with hadoop user account, eclipse can work normally, but the hadoop plugin cannot work, which means there is no map reduce option in window->preference menu. However, this plugin can work under my normal user account. This problem drives me crazy!!! thanks for your help!

Comment: That is probably because the plugin is installed in your user directory so hadoop does not have it. Either copy your user folder to `/home/hadoop` or reinstall the plugin as hadoop.

Comment: I uninstall eclipse and reinstall it under my hadoop account, then copy the plugin to /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins and /usr/share/eclipse/plugins, it still does not work.....